# Validation error on back button in Multistep Form

Tags: forms

Validation errors with a back button on Multistep form.

I used form alter for this but this is also not working below are my code.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{ if($form_id=='dataset_node_form')
{
 $form['actions']['previous']['#submit'][] = array(); 
 $form['actions']['previous']['#limit_validation_errors']=array(); 
}
}
```

Comment: Please describe what exactly is happening and show us some code.

Comment: I am using multistep form with four step i.e(step1,step2,step3--) on step2 there are some required fields so if i go to step2 and wants to come in step1 with out filling required field of step2 then it always shows validation error and do not go to step1 from step2.

Comment: I used form alter for this but this is also not working below are my code.function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    if($form_id=='dataset_node_form'){
       $form['actions']['previous']['#submit'][] = array();
       $form['actions']['previous']['#limit_validation_errors']=array();
    }
  }

Answer (score 0):

Enable devel module. Then put a dpm to make sure that your code is being called.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){   if($form_id=='dataset_node_form')
{
 dpm($form, 'From my custom module');
 $form['actions']['previous']['#submit'][] = array(); 
 $form['actions']['previous']['#limit_validation_errors']=array(); 
}
}
```

If your message shows up then some other module is overriding your form_alter. You can implement `hook_module_implements_alter` in your custom module to make sure that the form_alter of your module is called last.

Comment: after using hook_module_implements_alter() it is not working.

Comment: Is there any options for creating multistep form?